# google CloudSQL mysql emoji (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x80\\xF0\\x9F...' for column 'name' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I can't make it to post emojis to the database when I use my-app.appspot.com
but when I run it locally `python manage.py runserver`with the same libraries on GAE everything works perfectly and I can post and retrieve emojis .

here is my settings .py

```
import os
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/my-app:us-central1:my-app-mysql',
            'NAME': '********',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '*********',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': '*******',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '*********',
            'HOST': '**********',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'OPTIONS': {
                 'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the charset when using cloud shell

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

and here is the charset when I connect using the IP of the database from another client

```
Variable_name                        Value
character_set_client                utf8
character_set_connection            utf8mb4
character_set_database              utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem            binary
character_set_results               utf8
character_set_server                utf8mb4
character_set_system                utf8
collation_connection                utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database                  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server                    utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I'm I missing something ?!!

how do I make work?

thanks
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton/issues/28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> waprin: @EssaAlshammri reproduced, filed internal bug with engineering team, will keep you updated.

from [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton/issues/28)

> You can try base64 encoding going in and out of the database as a workaround.

it works fine.

you can wait until they fix the issue